# Java client library for Grafana Loki

Tags: java, grafana, statsd, grafana-loki

Currently we are using statsd java client to push certain application data to graphite. We build dashboards in Grafana using this data.

I am planning to switch to Grafana Loki. I was wondering if its possible to push certain data directly to Grafana Loki using a daemon like statsd . Are there are any java client libraries to do so. If so please give me maven repository link.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Loki4j Logback appender  https://github.com/loki4j/loki-logback-appender (disclosure: I'm an author of it).

Loki4j is pure Java client for Loki with flexible formatting options for labels and log messages. It supports both JSON and Protobuf flavors of Loki push API. You should be able to push any data you want directly to Loki using Loki4j.

Comment: Hi, I tried using it but did not work. I configured the logback.xml with http url and I am using the org.slf4j.Logger class to use logger.debug("logs")

Comment: @VasanthNagKV It looks like a misconfiguration issue. Please check if there are any error messages in stderr, they could help you to fix the config. Also you can report an issue to GitHub project, so we can dig into this together.

Comment: There is no error and no logs written, I guess I am doing something wrong in a very basic sense. I will anyway report it on github, thanks. Also the documentation for loki4j is very minimum I feel. about some configs and examples. Just a request for more examples. thanks

Comment: Who use the log4j library with other Java applications, should take some proactive measures, which they can take to reduce the risk posed by CVE-2021-44228.

Answer (score 2):

There is documentation page with Loki unofficial clients here:

- https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/#unofficial-clients

There is also my zero dependency pure Java 1.8 library for desktop and Android. Not well optimized but very simple to adopt as independent log sender with custom labels:

- https://github.com/mjfryc/mjaron-tinyloki-java

Import library:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'io.github.mjfryc:mjaron-tinyloki-java:0.3.11'
}
```

and then:

```java
import pl.mjaron.tinyloki.*;

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LogController logController = TinyLoki
                .withUrl("http://localhost/loki/api/v1/push")
                .withBasicAuth("user", "pass")
                .start();

        ILogStream stream = logController.stream() // Before v0.3.2 use createStream()
                .info()
                .l("host", "MyComputerName")
                .l("customLabel", "custom_value")
                .build();

        stream.log("Hello world.");
        logController.softStop().hardStop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have crated a [Java client](https://github.com/tkowalcz/tjahzi) for pushing logs to Loki. There is a log4j appender built on top of it (at my employers it is used on production to push 10s of GB of logs daily).

It is designed to be lock free and allocation free on logging path. Uses Netty so sending batches to Loki allocates, but it's very efficient.

Comment: Who use the log4j library with other Java applications, should take some proactive measures, which they can take to reduce the risk posed by CVE-2021-44228.

Comment: @vladimirvojtisek you are absolutely right. I have updated my library to use Log4j2 2.16.0 that fixes the CVE.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use one of the [supported clients](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/)